# Code gives an error and uses commands that we are not meant to use

Tags: python, assembly, mips

Need help with fixing the following MIPS code which was translated from Python code that is meant to read a list of integers of a size given and compute the minimum element in the list. I also can't use the commands li, blez, bnez or move so if there are alternative ways to write those segments, that would be helpful too. Thank you :)

**Python:**

```
size = int(input(”Enter list size : ”))

the list = [0] ∗ size

for i in range(size):
    the list[i] = int(input(”Enter element ”+ str(i) + ”: ”))

if size > 0:
    min = the list[0]
    for i in range(1,size):
        item = the list[i] 
        if min > item:
            min = item
     print( ”The minimum element in this list is ” + str(min) + ”\n ”)
```

**MIPS:**

```
    .data
prompt: .asciiz "\n How many integer numbers? (5 integers, minimum) "
result: .asciiz "The minimum integer is "

    .text
    .globl main
main:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt
    syscall

    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    blez $v0, end
    li $t0, 0
loop:
    add $t0, $t0, $v0
    addi $v0, $v0, -1
    bnez $v0, loop

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, result
    syscall
    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t0
    syscall
    b main
end:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0,
    syscall
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. It would be helpful to know where are you having difficulies exactly.

Comment: `bne $v0, $zero, end` is the same as `bnez`.  MIPS has BNE/BEQ for a pair of registers as a native hardware instruction, not a pseudo-instruction.  Is this supposed to be a [mcve] for a debugging question?  There are a ton of things that don't make sense in your code, like `bnez $v0, loop` creating a tight loop that does `do { t0 += v0; }while(--v0);`, but I don't see why you need to sum a series.  Use a debugger to see what your code does and find simple mistakes before taking up other people's time with it.